# Eu posso setar o else para fazer duas coisas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Eu quero fazer uma função para caso o nome inserido seja inválido, o programa exiba que o nome está inválido e além disso, feche o programa ou retorne para o ponto inicial, isso é possível em Python?

```
 carro = str(input('Qual carro você alugou? '))

if carro == 'Peugeot':
        c = 50
elif carro == 'C3':
        c = 60
elif carro == 'Cruze':
        c = 70
elif carro == 'CRV':
        c = 75
else:
        print('O carro digitado não está cadastrado no nosso sistema. Verifique se está digitado corretamente ou comunique a empresa.')
```

se for possível, qual a maneira de eu dividir as funções, por exemplo

```
print('O carro digitado não está cadastrado no nosso sistema. Verifique se está digitado corretamente ou comunique a empresa.'), return line1
```

ou

```
print('O carro digitado não está cadastrado no nosso sistema. Verifique se está digitado corretamente ou comunique a empresa.') and return line1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assim?

```
if carro == 'Peugeot':
    c = 50
elif carro == 'C3':
    c = 60
elif carro == 'Cruze':
    c = 70
elif carro == 'CRV':
    c = 75
else:
    print('O carro digitado não está cadastrado no nosso sistema. Verifique se está digitado corretamente ou comunique a empresa.')
    return #ou pode usar sys.exit() se quiser acabar de vez
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Else.py).

Não há problema algum em colocar várias linhas em cada bloco.

Comment: Não sabia disso, valeu ae